# Can Eureka and Warehouse 13 exist in the same universe?

Tags: eureka, warehouse-13

At the start of the last UK series of Eureka ( series 4 I think ) and Warehouse 13 ( Series 3? ) there is a swapping over of characters. Claudia visited Eureka and Fargo visited the warehouse. Which I think is cool, because it messes with my head.

However, it seems that there are fundamental differences in the world-view between these two. I accept that neither tries to be entirely and completely consistent, but Warehouse deals with "supernatural" artefacts, things that cause behaviour that is not empircally proveable. Most of the time, people have left their "influence" on objects.

Whereas in Eureka, everything is ameneable to scientific exploration. The concept of an artefact that somehow retains the influence of its user, without having had some Eureka magic on it, would be ridiculous.

So how can they actually co-exist?

Comment: really bothers me when shows with geeky fan-bases do this. Like including the E.T. species in Star Wars.

Comment: I think it is quite fun, but I accept that it is not for everyone. I liked when Nathan Fillion in Castle was going to dress up as a Space Cowboy, and his daughter said "That was 4 years ago" - all relating to his Malcolm Reynolds character in Firefly.

Comment: They also had Dr. Calder show up on *Alphas*, so all 3 shows are technically in the same universe.

Comment: @DVK: The other question is specifically about same actors appearing in different roles in both shows. This one is about fundamental differences between shows' premises.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat I about fell out of my chair when I saw that scene, but I think it's a different thing. In Castle it was a nod at Fillion/Firefly fans, whereas in Eureka/Warehouse 13 it's a straight-up cross-over.

Comment: DVK - I read the Goof question, but I think this one is different. That is about how the ymixed them up, but this is about whether they are actually compatible, in-universe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main real-world reason is probably that both shows are produced by the same company, and they figured a cross over would increase the fanbase (by making a pitch of one series to already established fans of another one).

The most plausible in-universe explanation could be in that *Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic*. Since Eureka is about science and technology and Warehouse 13 about magic, that is the one thing connecting them. You can think of Warehouse 13 artifacts as of really really advanced pieces of technology. Even Eureka had one of these in early seasons, and it was even called The Artifact.

Comment: I appreciate the real-world reasons, and I think from that perspective, it was quite clever cross marketing. But if Eureka can understand them, why can they not also deal with them better?

Comment: They actually raise this point in the Warehouse 13 pilot. I don't know the exact wording but Artie said "What would Benjamin Franklin do if you showed him a FM radio. He would think it is magic, lock it up, and study it."